# npm/pnpm run dev showing permission issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, next.js, pnpm

This issue doesn't come when I run the same command with `sudo`, as expected. What am I missing here? I've checked for similar posts here, and generally. The same goes for `npm run dev`. Both `npm` and `pnpm` have the same issue. `node_modules` was installed without any root permissions. No issues with `sudo npm run dev`/`sudo pnpm run dev`

```bash
someuser@someuser-normalUbuntu:~/projects/nextjs-dashboard$ pnpm run dev

> nextjs-dashboard@0.1.0 dev /home/someuser/projects/nextjs-dashboard
> next dev

   ▲ Next.js 14.0.4
   - Local:        http://localhost:3000
   - Environments: .env.development

Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/home/someuser/projects/nextjs-dashboard/.next/app-build-manifest.json'
    at async Object.unlink (node:internal/fs/promises:1059:10)
    at async unlinkPath (/home/someuser/projects/nextjs-dashboard/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.69.6/node_modules/next/dist/lib/recursive-delete.js:25:13)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async recursiveDelete (/home/someuser/projects/nextjs-dashboard/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.69.6/node_modules/next/dist/lib/recursive-delete.js:51:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/home/someuser/projects/nextjs-dashboard/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.69.6/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:147:20)
    at async HotReloader.start (/home/someuser/projects/nextjs-dashboard/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.69.6/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader-webpack.js:587:9)
    at async startWatcher (/home/someuser/projects/nextjs-dashboard/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.69.6/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js:1197:5)
    at async setupDevBundler (/home/someuser/projects/nextjs-dashboard/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.69.6/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js:1812:20)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/home/someuser/projects/nextjs-dashboard/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.69.6/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:147:20)
    at async initialize (/home/someuser/projects/nextjs-dashboard/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.69.6/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:72:30) {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'unlink',
  path: '/home/someuser/projects/nextjs-dashboard/.next/app-build-manifest.json'
}
```

I use Ubuntu 22.04.

```bash
someuser@someuser-normalUbuntu:~$ node -v
v21.6.2
someuser@someuser-normalUbuntu:~$ npm -v
10.2.4
someuser@someuser-normalUbuntu:~$ pnpm -v
8.15.3
```

It works when I do

```bash
sudo chown -R ${USER} folder_name
```

But that doesn't solve the larger issue

Comment: @mandy8055 Yes, it works with `sudo chmod -R 755 /directory/path`. I though this was an issue with npm itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the permission your project(`nextjs-dashboard`) directory has which is not allowing you to execute and install dependencies and peer dependencies. To resolve it so that your particular directory has proper permissions:

1. Change the ownership of your project directory recursively, so your user has full control over it which you've already tried.
   `sudo chown -R ${USER} /home/someuser/projects/nextjs-dashboard`
2. Set the proper permissions for your project directory which is required.
   `sudo chmod -R 755 /home/someuser/projects/nextjs-dashboard`